# Espresso Android - how to check relative objects?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I would like to check if the address (in the attached image) has its heart icon.

The address id – `R.id.fav_name_tv`

The heart icon id – `R.id.fav_icon`

How do I build the script with `childAtPosition` / `hasParent` / `hasSibling`?

attached pic below

[image]

Comment: Is the a view that is added/removed or shown/hidden on demand?

Comment: press on the icon and the address will move to the favorite addresses section

Comment: Can you post the code that you use for this: "move to the favourite addresses section"?
Depending on that, the solution to your problem might be different.

Answer (score 0):

if your icon is a drawable then you can check it in a imageview you can try

`onView(withId(R.id.image_view_id)).check(matches(withDrawable(R.drawable.your_icon)));`

hope it helps